# display the question to accept or reject the request from the sender

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, communication, wifi

i created a application to communicate with another devices through WiFi network.For that application i simply searching all the available devices that are connected in my same wifi network and will list out all the available devices on a Table View.When i click on the device name it will communicate(send a string msg) with the selected device.there is no question to accept or reject the request from the sender.How can i do that?can i communicate with multiple devices at a time over wifi network?please tell me the way to do the two processes.

Answer (score 0):

"can i communicate with multiple devices at a time over wifi network?please tell me the way to do the two processes." yes, its simply done with sockets. You would be using multiple sockets at the same time.

"When i click on the device name it will communicate(send a string msg) with the selected device.there is no question to accept or reject the request from the sender." you would need to implement some kind of protocol here to allow the recipient to ignore incoming requests or data from the originator.

Look into using Bounjour to advertise yourself or GameKit for making connections.